# Where do I establish a database connection inside of a Python class for running multiple queries?

Tags: python, database, pymysql

I'm writing a class that involves multiple `INSERT` statements, split into different functions. Say for example I'm writing a class for `employeeStart` where when an employee starts working, I'm given a staff name and insert that value into table 'staff' of grain `staff_id | staff_name`. The `staff_id` is an auto_increment field so it populates itself with a new value.

And then I grab that staff_id value and insert it into table 'badge' which has a grain of `badge_number | staff_id` where `bade_number` is also auto increment.

So the class looks like:

```
class employeeStart:
    staff_id = None
    badge_number = None

    def __init__(self, staff_name):
        self.staff_id = setStaffId(staff_name)
        self.badge_number = setBadgeNumber(staff_id)
```

This is all on a Mysql database, so I establish the database connection just once, right? If so, where should that happen? Would it be before the `__init__` function, inside the `__init__` function, or in the first function that will run - `setStaffId`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the contex manager syntax of [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) to handle the connection and the error handling, wrapping the queries in a `with` statement.

```
import MySQLdb

class employeeStart:

    def set_staff_id(self, connection):
        with connection as cursor:           
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO staff (name) VALUES (%s)", staff_name)
            return cursor.lastrowid

    def set_badge_id(self, connection):
        with connection as cursor:           
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO badge (staffid) VALUES (%s)", staff_id)
            return cursor.lastrowid

    def __init__(self):
        connection = MySQLdb.connect(...)
        self.staff_id = self.set_staf_id(connection)
        self.badge_id = self.set_badge_id(connection)
```

But I do not really see the need for a class here...